# Laravel Blade @guest directive for multiple guards

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the user guard (which name is `web`) and I have the admin guard (which name is `admin`). So, to show/hide stuff I use the Laravel blade directives `@auth('web')` or `@auth('admin')` but somehow the `@guest` doesn't work so I'm forced to use like this:

```
@auth('admin')
    <li>Dashboard</li>
    <li>Log out</li>
@endauth

@auth('web')
    <li>Create Post</li>
    <li>Log out</li>
@endauth

@guest('admin')
    @guest('web')
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>About us</li>
    @endguest
@endguest
```

I nest the guest directives but it feels like too much, any better way of doing it?

Comment: Do you really have two levels of Guest?  How are you determining if an unauthenticated user is admin or not???

Comment: Nope I mean I have three guards: web (for users), api (I don't use this one) and admind (for admins). I want to display contact and about us for unauthenticated users (neither users nor admins). But if I use @guest alone without ('admin') or ('web') it shows for everyone: guests, users, and admins

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: using laravel 5.5.12

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this - using Laravel 5.4.36.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @guest
        <li>I'm a guest</li>
    @endauth
    <li>{{ Html::link(url('/consultants'), 'Consultants') }}</li>
    <li>{{ Html::link(url('/clients'), 'Clients') }}</li>
    <li>{{ Html::link(url('/tasks'), 'Tasks') }}</li>
</ul>
```

The 'I'm a guest' is only displayed to unathenticated users, as expected.

I noticed that you had `@endguest` and not `@endauth` - is that just a typo here?

Update:  if you do this, does it work how you would expect?

```
@auth('admin')
    <li>Dashboard</li>
    <li>Log out</li>
@endauth

@auth('web')
    <li>Create Post</li>
    <li>Log out</li>
@endauth

@guest
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>About us</li>
@endauth
```

Comment: BTW The @guest directive work but only for the web guard